# Verificar se há retorno da imagem via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Como verificar se a imagem retornou com erro 404 via javascript.

Abaixo um codigo de exemplo, quero verificar se o get dessa imagem é 404. Se for quero colocar uma determinada imagem, se não for retornar a imagem.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/438827041199099904/ZLjBL8Tg_normal.jpeg" alt=""/ id="teste">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma outra solução vinda [do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019077/detecting-a-image-404-in-javascript) baseada em [um artigo](http://web.archive.org/web/20120904060007/http://lucassmith.name/2008/11/is-my-image-loaded.html) que hoje já não existe mais (link dos Arquivos).

```
// First a couple helper functions
function $(id) {
    return !id || id.nodeType === 1 ? id : document.getElementById(id);
}
function isType(o,t) {    return (typeof o).indexOf(t.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) === 0;}

// Here's the meat and potatoes
function image(src,cfg) {    var img, prop, target;
    cfg = cfg || (isType(src,'o') ? src : {});

    img = $(src);
    if (img) {
        src = cfg.src || img.src;
    } else {
        img = document.createElement('img');
        src = src || cfg.src;
    }

    if (!src) {
        return null;
    }

    prop = isType(img.naturalWidth,'u') ? 'width' : 'naturalWidth';
    img.alt = cfg.alt || img.alt;

    // Add the image and insert if requested (must be on DOM to load or
    // pull from cache)
    img.src = src;

    target = $(cfg.target);
    if (target) {
        target.insertBefore(img, $(cfg.insertBefore) || null);
    }

    // Loaded?
    if (img.complete) {
        if (img[prop]) {
            if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
                cfg.success.call(img);
            }
        } else {
            if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
                cfg.failure.call(img);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (isType(cfg.success,'f')) {
            img.onload = cfg.success;
        }
        if (isType(cfg.failure,'f')) {
            img.onerror = cfg.failure;
        }
    }

    return img;
}
```

Uso:

```
image('http://somedomain.com/image/typooed_url.jpg', {
    success : function () {alert(this.width)},
    failure : function () {alert('Oops!')}
});

image('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/bac48b9b301f4b2aea7ec399a14b8bc9?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG', {
    success : function () {/** ... */},
    failure : function () {alert('Oops!')},
    target : 'successImageContainer'
});
```

Demo [no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LMJB/).

A primeira vista parece recurso em excesso, mas se for ver, caso resulte num 404 você teria que fazer algumas condições e tal então alguns callbacks vêm bem a calhar.

Comment: Poxa ! Completo @BrunoAugusto, muito bom mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar um listener para o evento `onerror`:

```
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/438827041199099904/ZLjBL8Tg_normal.jpeg" alt=""/ id="teste">
<script>
document.getElementById('teste').onerror = function() {
    alert('Xi, deu erro!');
}
</script>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, mas fiz aqui o teste e ele não faz o alert, é como se retornasse algo. Mas se você acessar essa imagem vai ver que dá erro no console 404.

Comment: Fiz um teste e pareceu funcionar: http://jsbin.com/saritewu/1/edit

Comment: Rolou aqui @bfaretto. Valeu mesmo :)

Comment: Nesse link dos Arquivos que eu mencionei na minha resposta o autor lista uma série de peculiaridades antre browsers quanto ao onerror (e onload). JS não é bem meu forte pra dizer se confiar completamente (e unicamente) no onerror é seguro ou não.

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoAugusto, li o link.

Comment: E então? Isso influencia em alguma coisa?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Pelo que entendi, grosso modo, o maior problema é com cache. Se o objetivo é controlar o carregamento de algo que pode ou não estar acessível, intermitentemente, `onerror` pode ser problema. Se é pra checar se um recurso não existe nem nunca existiu, `onerror` deve ser suficiente.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer uma requisição `HEAD` e verificar o status de retorno da *url*.

```
function checkStatus(imageUrl) 
{
   var http = jQuery.ajax(
   {
      type:"HEAD",
      url: imageUrl,
      async: false
    })
  return http.status;
}
```

E utilizá-la desse modo:

```
var imageUrl = 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/438827041199099904/ZLjBL8Tg_normal.jpeg';
var statuscode = checkStatus(imageUrl);

if (statuscode == 200)
{
   // Existe!
} else if (statuscode == 404)
{
   // Não existe!
}
// else if....
```

Comment: beleza, vou testar dessa forma.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer um `load` na url da imagem para verificar se existe:

```
function checkImagem(url) {
  var img = '<img src="'+ url +'" />';
  $(img).load(function() {
    $('body').append(url+img);
  }).bind('error', function() {
    alert('imagem: '+url+' não existe');
  });
 }
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8jP6/)**

Comment: Para funcionar nas novas versões da JQuery use assim `$(img).on("load", function() {`